# populate list with images from database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, list, listview

I want to retrieve the images from SQL table and save it in the list and show it in my listview. But I don't know how to do this. I need your help.

I am using SQL Server 2008, Visual Studio 2008, C# Window Application.

Here is my code:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ScanImage from ScanDocuments", con);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

List<ImageList> lstitem = new List<ImageList>();

while (dr.Read())
{
    ImageList _image = new ImageList();
    byte[] data = (byte[])dr["ScanImage"];

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
    Image bmp = new Bitmap(ms);

    lstitem.Add(bmp);
}
```

Comment: Show us some effort of your own! What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What are the issues you're struggling with??

Comment: kindly view my edited question. I am getting error at lstitem.add(bmp);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several flaws - you need to use something like this instead:

```
// define connection string and select statement
// I used AdventureWorks 2012 database - change to match *YOUR* environment
string connectionString = "server=.;database=AdventureWorks2012;integrated security=SSPI;";
string query = "SELECT ThumbNailPhoto FROM Production.ProductPhoto";

// define a list of "Image" objects 
List<Image> listOfImages = new List<Image>();

// using the SqlConnection and SqlCommand ....
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand selectCmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
     // open connection
     conn.Open();

     // execute SqlCommand to return a SqlDataReader
     using (SqlDataReader rdr = selectCmd.ExecuteReader())
     {
         // iterate over the reader
         while (rdr.Read())
         {
              // load the bytes from the database that represent your image
              var imageBytes = (byte[]) rdr[0];

              // put those bytes into a memory stream and "rewind" the memory stream
              MemoryStream memStm = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
              memStm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

              // create an "Image" from that memory stream
              Image image = Image.FromStream(memStm);

              // add image to list 
              listOfImages.Add(image);
         }
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

This works just fine for me - it loads the 101 `ThumbNailPhoto` from the `AdventureWorks2012` database